# Why is my PhoneGap app graphics corrupted only on iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, graphics, phonegap, corruption

The following is a **shortened** version of the real code. I use PhoneGap to implement an algorithm that takes my 2 designs - one for portrait and one for landscape - and switch between them as needed, including automatic scaling to the center of the specific screen. It works great on Android, but there appears to be some unexplained corruption of the tab graphics on iPhone, upon switching between modes (portrait / landscape) and clicking the tabs.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main" class="main">
      <div id="ext" class="extPortrait">
        <div id="tabDiv1" class="tabDiv1Portrait">
          <img id="tabImg1" class="tabImg" src="img/tabImgPortrait.png" draggable="false" />
          <div id="tabTxt1" class="tabTxt">Tab1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabDiv2" class="tabDiv2Portrait">
          <img id="tabImg2" class="tabImg" src="img/tabImgPortrait.png" draggable="false" />
          <div id="tabTxt2" class="tabTxt">Tab2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {direction:ltr; margin:0; border:0; padding:0;
  background-color:#c9c9c9; font-family:Calibri,Arial;
  font-size:14px; color:#0070b8; overflow:auto;}

.main {display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
  width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; border:0; padding:0;
  background-color:#c9c9c9; overflow:hidden; z-index:10;}

.extPortrait, .extLandscape {display:block; position:absolute;
  margin:0; border:2px solid; border-radius:6px; padding:0;
  background-color:#f4f4f4; border-color:#bcbcbc; z-index:20;}
.extPortrait {top:3.409%; left:4.444%; width:90%;     height:93.344%;}
.extLandscape {top:6.25%;  left:2.5%;   width:94.375%; height:87.798%;}

.tabDiv1Portrait, .tabDiv2Portrait, .tabDiv1Landscape, .tabDiv2Landscape
  {display:block; position:absolute; margin:0; border:0; padding:0;
  overflow:hidden; cursor:pointer; z-index:30;}
.tabDiv1Portrait, .tabDiv2Portrait
  {top:-1.913%; width:21.605%; height:7.304%; font-size:2.922%;}
.tabDiv1Landscape, .tabDiv2Landscape
  {top:-3.729%; width:23.179%; height:14.237%; font-size:5.357%;}
.tabDiv1Portrait {left:8.642%;}
.tabDiv2Portrait {left:31.481%;}
.tabDiv1Landscape {left:4.636%;}
.tabDiv2Landscape {left:28.477%;}

.tabImg {display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
  width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; border:0; padding:0;
  cursor:pointer; z-index:40;}

.tabTxt {display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
  width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; border:0; padding:0;
  line-height:233%; color:#ffffff; text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer; z-index:50;}
```

The JavaScript:

```
var PMYWID = 360, PMYHIG = 616;  //sizes of my portrait design
var LMYWID = 640, LMYHIG = 336;  //sizes of my landscape design
var scrWid = 0, scrHig = 0;
var portrait = true;
var tabNum = 0;

(function() {
  window.onload = function() {
    mobilePeriodicCheck();
    tab1Clk();
    document.getElementById("tabDiv1").addEventListener("click", tab1Clk);
    document.getElementById("tabDiv2").addEventListener("click", tab2Clk);
    //document.getElementById("main").style.display = "block";
  }
}());

function mobilePeriodicCheck() {
  var scrWidNew = window.innerWidth, scrHigNew = window.innerHeight;
  if ((scrWidNew != scrWid) || (scrHigNew != scrHig)) {
    scrWid = scrWidNew;
    scrHig = scrHigNew;
    portrait = (scrWid <= scrHig);
    var wid,hig,lef;
    if (portrait) {
      if (scrWid/scrHig <= PMYWID/PMYHIG) { wid = scrWid; hig = Math.floor(PMYHIG*scrWid/PMYWID); lef = 0;}
      else { wid = Math.floor(PMYWID*scrHig/PMYHIG); hig = scrHig; lef = Math.floor((scrWid-wid)/2);}
    }
    else {
      if (scrWid/scrHig <= LMYWID/LMYHIG) { wid = scrWid; hig = Math.floor(LMYHIG*scrWid/LMYWID); lef = 0;}
      else { wid = Math.floor(LMYWID*scrHig/LMYHIG); hig = scrHig; lef = Math.floor((scrWid-wid)/2);}
    }
    var id = document.getElementById("main");
    id.style.width = wid + "px";
    id.style.height = hig + "px";
    id.style.left = lef + "px";
    id.style.fontSize = hig + "px";
    document.getElementById("ext").className = portrait ? "extPortrait" : "extLandscape";
    document.getElementById("tabDiv1").className = portrait ? "tabDiv1Portrait" : "tabDiv1Landscape";
    document.getElementById("tabDiv2").className = portrait ? "tabDiv2Portrait" : "tabDiv2Landscape";
    document.getElementById("tabImg1").src = portrait ? "img/tabImgPortrait.png" : "img/tabImgLandscape.png";
    document.getElementById("tabImg2").src = portrait ? "img/tabImgPortrait.png" : "img/tabImgLandscape.png";
  }
  setTimeout(mobilePeriodicCheck, 1000);
}

function tab1Clk() { tabClk(1); }
function tab2Clk() { tabClk(2); }
function tabClk(iTab) {
  if (iTab!=tabNum) {
    if (tabNum > 0) {
      document.getElementById("tabImg"+tabNum).style.WebkitFilter = "brightness(100%)";
      document.getElementById("tabImg"+tabNum).style.filter = "brightness(100%)";
    }
    document.getElementById("tabImg"+iTab).style.WebkitFilter = "brightness(135%)";
    document.getElementById("tabImg"+iTab).style.filter = "brightness(135%)";
    tabNum = iTab;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a lot with this, I think I found the problem: At least one of `style.WebkitFilter` and `style.filter` causes rendering problems in iOS WebView. I switched to simply changing the `src` of the image, and that worked perfectly on both platforms.